# using virtualProc with gcc in windows

Tags: windows, gcc

i created different sections in my executable like this:

```
objdump -h Os_MemoryProtectionTest_tests_SingleCore_SC3_i386_MinGW.exe

Os_MemoryProtectionTest_tests_SingleCore_SC3_i386_MinGW.exe:     file format pei                              -i386

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn

  0 .text         00006d64  00401000  00401000  00000a00  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE, DATA

  1 OsMemorySectionOsApplicationTestCode 00000e5c  00408000  00408000 00007800                                2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE

  2 OS_PRIVATE_CODE 0000918c  00409000  00409000  00008800  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
```

now if i use `virtualProtect()` function of windows, does every section is already in separate page?
if not then how can i assure that each section is in separate page to be able to use `VirtualProtect()`.

Comment: wow - thank you Zaidi for re-editing, look much prettier now :D,

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I believe that sections are *always* loaded at page boundaries.